# SwiftUI firebase - change user's displayName - how to refresh view instantly

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I've created a basic firebase login app using swiftui (using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhLEwqyVSjE). Everything works as it should.

In my ContentView.swift I added a TextField for changing the user's display name. To do this, I added a changeDisplayName func in the SessionStore.swift with this logic:

```
let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
changeRequest?.displayName = displayName
changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

The func is called by a button in my ContentView. Changing the displayName works aswell, but my ContentView still holds the old displayName until I restart the app, because only then the ContentView calls `session.listen()` again and gets the new displayName from the SessionStore.

To fix this, I call `session.unbind()` and then `session.listen()` in my ContentView whenever the changeDisplayName func in my SessionStore is called by my ContentView and doesn't return an error. This works and my ContentView is reloaded with the new displayName everytime it is changed.

**Is this good practice or am I missing a cleaner solution to this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload()`. This may not work because I've had trouble in the past with isEmailVerified but I guess it's worth a try!

Comment: Then I think your solution is the best one. It reloads the user fine, but the authenticationStateListener I was using to listen to the verifiedEmail state did not update.